# proxy.writeQuery weird behavior

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I have a todo app (react-native) with graphql-client connect

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: API,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

when I add a new todo or delete, I need to update the cache so the changes could show without refreshing

```
createTodo({
        variables: { text: todo },
        update(proxy, result) {
          const data = proxy.readQuery({
            query: FETCH_TODOS
          });
          data.getTodos = [result.data.createTodo, ...data.getTodos];
          proxy.writeQuery({
            query: FETCH_TODOS,
            data
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

the problem is, I had to call the writeQuery inside the item's component. and if I invoked it in the form component. Nothing happened. why?

**update**
this code worked just fine, but the createTodo did not.

```
const hanglePress = key => {
    deleteTodo({
      variables: { todoId: key },
      update(proxy) {
        const data = proxy.readQuery({
          query: FETCH_TODOS
        });
        data.getTodos = data.getTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== key);
        proxy.writeQuery({ query: FETCH_TODOS, data });
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: 'show without refreshing' - refreshing (rerendering some component) is for showing changes

Comment: If you're using the exact same code and it's working in one component and not in another, it's not clear what could be wrong just from what you posted. You should update your question to show the code that is working and the code that isn't.

Comment: @DanielRearden Actually, it's the same piece of code in both components.
The only difference is "createTodo" and the other is "deleteTodo".
when I call the deleteTodo inside the item's component with the update method, it works fine. but inside the form component, it's not. I solved it by lifting the state to the item's component and it worked there. but I don't understand why it didn't work there.

Comment: Like I said, if the component works in one component but not another, then we'd need to see how it's being used inside both components to determine what the cause is